# Linq to Entity convert string to proper case

Tags: linq-to-entities

Could you show me an example how to convert string when I am selecting using Linq to entity to proper case? Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper Case Title Case Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844248/proper-case-title-case-question)

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you need purely LINQ for this.

Have a look at this example

```
string sampleString = "this is a title";
CultureInfo currentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo currentInfo = currentCulture.TextInfo;
sampleString = currentInfo.ToTitleCase(sampleString); 

//output:
//This Is A Title
```

[TextInfo.ToTitleCase Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx)

So in a LINQ select you could use something like

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo currentInfo = currentCulture.TextInfo;
List<string> testList = new List<string> { "foo", "bAr", "fOO bar Test tAdA" };
var correct = from s in testList
              select currentInfo.ToTitleCase(s);
```

Comment: In my case I'm binding datalist with linq to entity, thats why I need to convert when Im selecting

Comment: I have some data like TABLE, WORD, APPLE and I need to convert them to  Table, Word, Apple ...

Comment: Then this should help you with that.