# Proper Case Title Case Question

Tags: c#

What am i doing wrong here? I want the users name to be shown in the output as propercase but I cant figure it out.

```
string proper = this.xTripNameTextBox.Text;
CultureInfo properCase = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo currentInfo = properCase.TextInfo;
proper = currentInfo.ToTitleCase(proper);

this.xTripOutputLabel.Text = proper +  Environment.NewLine + "The total gallons you would use: " + Output.ToString("0") + Environment.NewLine + "Total amount it will cost you: " + Coutput.ToString("C") + Environment.NewLine +" Your customer number is " + rnd1.Next(1, 1000).ToString();
```

Comment: Can you show us what you are getting and what you expect?

Comment: When a user enters "JOHN DOE" I get "JOHN DOE" it's supposed to convert it to propercase "John Doe", but I don't know what im doing wrong

Comment: That is the problem, use ToLower to first convert the string to lower case, then the Title casing will work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Entity convert string to proper case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708866/linq-to-entity-convert-string-to-proper-case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have tested the following on an all upper case word at it works:

```
string proper = "TEST STRING";
CultureInfo properCase = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo currentInfo = properCase.TextInfo;
proper = currentInfo.ToTitleCase(currentInfo.ToLower(proper));
// proper = "Test String"
```

So - change the string to lower case before calling `ToTitleCase`.

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) documentation does say that a string that is all upper case (such as an acronym) will not be converted and the sample code provided in the post corroborates this.

Answer (score 3):

That's according to spec, quote from the doc: *However, this method does not currently provide proper casing to convert a word that is entirely uppercase*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx

Without testing I'd guess that you could do it by first making it `LowerCase` and then `TitleCase`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems right, I am using

```
return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text);
```

And it's working.

Try to force another culture info.

See Also

- [How to capitalize the first character of each word, or the first character of a whole string, with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913090/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-or-the-first-character-of-a-w)